# CdiCamelContext versus CamelContext

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and the project I'm working in is using both `org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext` and `org.apache.camel.CamelContext` in different components. What is the difference between these classes?

Answer (score 0):

`CdiCamelContext` is the CamelContext implementation (its a class) when using camel-cdi, and running on a CDI container. The `CamelContext` is the generic API of CamelContext, eg its an interface.